# How to verify GCM sender ID of deviceToken in Parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

We are using Parse.com to send push notifications. With the announced shutdown, we're now looking into how to migrate to another service. On Android, we haven't configured any GCM sender ID so we have been implicitly using Parse.com's sender ID. That's a problem for the migration (see [Urgent note for Parse Android Push users](https://onesignal.com/blog/important-note-for-android-parse-push-users/) and [Migrating an Existing Parse App](https://parse.com/docs/server/guide#migrating) (section *Exporting GCM Registration IDs*)).

Therefore, we are now preparing a new version of our Android app with our own GCM sender ID. Is there any way in Parse.com to verify which devices (*installation*) are associated with our sender ID? How can we check if our update was successful? Does Google provide any API for directly or indirectly checking if a sender ID works with our Google project?

Any tool or any approach that involves writing some code is ok.

Comment: what is the server side language you are using for this ?

Comment: So far we use Parse.com's REST API to send push notifications (from Java). But the question equally applies if we would use Parse.com's console (and no programming language at all).

Comment: okay.still you don't wanna use programming languages like php or asp.net?

Comment: Just tell me how I can verify if and what phones are now associated with our own sender ID. I can easily come up with code later once I understand the approach.

Comment: after seeing some article on web,i figured out that there should be some option in their DB to know number of users associated with your own sender ID.If there is no such option,then we have to wait until parse.com provide migration tools.

Comment: and more over you annot rely on third party GCM providers.It is always recommended to code yourself !!else use this https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2015-06-24-sending-receiving-android-push-notifications-with-gcm-google-cloud-messaging/

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for posting this question. I help work on OneSignal and I've updated the mentioned blog post based on the feedback.

The blog post now instructs users to also update their ParseInstallation to set their GCMSenderId, as follows:

```
final ParseInstallation parseInstallation = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
parseInstallation.put("GCMSenderId",YOUR_NEW_SENDER_ID); 
parseInstallation.saveInBackground();`
```

This will allow you to track which users are now subscribed with the new GCM Sender ID. It will also tell our Parse importing tools like ours that these subscribed devices can be imported and used.

Answer (score 0):

The open source Parse Server project does not currently support push notifications, but it is in the roadmap and should be available shortly.

If you wish to migrate your Parse Push app to another GCM provider, you will want to update your Android Manifest file with your own GCM Sender Id. Once the app has been deployed to the Google Play store, clients that update to the latest version of your app will register using your GCM Sender Id as well.

You will want to track how many of your active users have updated to the new version of the app to get a better idea of how well your migration is progressing.

The Parse Installation object automatically tracks the client-side app version number. A quick and easy way of determining how many clients have updated your app to the new version of your app is to filter for Installation objects running the new `appVersion` or newer.

You should, of course, make sure the updated version of your app has registered with GCM using your new Sender Id properly before you release the new version on the Google Play store. The [Android Documentation on Cloud Messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client) covers best practices for this. If your app has been configured correctly, you should be able to deliver push notifications to the updated clients using your new push notifications provider.

Comment: Are you sure? My understanding is that the `GCMSenderId` of the `Installation` object is used when migrating *to* Parse.com (not away from it) and that it must be explicitly set and is not automatically set by Parse.com. In fact, this field is empty for all our installations (according to the Parse.com console).

Comment: Just verified this, you're correct. In this case, you can explicitly set the GCMSenderId you're using from the client side. This should allow you to track which installations have been migrated over to your own sender id. If the GCMSenderId is not writeable, you should be able to use an arbitrary field on the Installation class to track this.

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding here. I don't want to write any data at Parse.com. Instead, I want to retrieve the data that Parse.com has stored automatically and verify if the device has been migrated to our own sender ID, which I have configured in our app manifest according to Parse.com's instruction. So which data do I need to read and how can I verify it?

Comment: I don't think there's any other way around it. Parse.com uses its own sender id unless the installation was imported with a different sender id. In your case, you're migrating to a different push service and you're updating your client to use your own sender id. Parse.com does not use this sender id for any purpose, and it is not tracked in the installation. If you need to track which devices are running your updated code (with the new sender id), you will need to track it somehow. This could be tracked on Parse.com, or somewhere else. The Installation object is the most convenient IMHO.

Comment: According to OneSignal, one can add the sender ID to the manifest, publish the app and have it running for a few month like this. After that, they can import the data from Parse.com and send push notifications to all devices that have run our app since the sender ID was added. I'm not sure if they can figure out up-front which devices work with our sender ID or if they only find out once they try to send a push notification. At least that's how I understood it. If one can somehow figure it out upfront, I would like to know how that works.

Comment: Updated answer with a solution that does not depend on writing data back to Parse. You will still want to look into writing some client side code to verify that the GCM registration was successful: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client

Comment: I'm sorry but I seem to be unable to explain to you what I'm looking for. Thanks for your effort anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can find information regarding sending and receiving push notifications from our guide: https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#push-notifications

In particular

...an advanced feature for developers that want to send pushes from multiple push providers, Parse allows you to optionally register your app for pushes with additional GCM sender IDs. To do this, specify the additional GCM sender ID with the following `<meta-data>` tag as a child of the `<application>` element in your app's AndroidManifest.xml...
and

GCMSenderId: This field only has meaning for Android ParseInstallations that use the GCM push type. It is reserved for directing Parse to send pushes to this installation with an alternate GCM sender ID. This field should generally not be set unless you are uploading installation data from another push provider. If you set this field, then you must set the GCM API key corresponding to this GCM sender ID in your Parse application's push settings.

Comment: I have a new app version ready where the sender ID is configured in the Android manifest. But how can we now verify that the devices with the updated app register with our own sender ID? I can't see that in your answer.